# iOS - Effect in the status bar

Tags: ios, swift

https://youtu.be/LUzFpdQYseQ

I need this loading effect in the status bar. How this can be made?
The video is recorded on iPhone XS Max.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add an image view to the top using [APNGKit](https://github.com/onevcat/APNGKit) or [SwiftyGif](https://github.com/kirualex/SwiftyGif)

Or you can play with `UIBezierPath`